# Question about continuous extensions

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking earlier about functions $f:\mathcal{N}\to \mathbb{R}$. Where $\mathcal{N}$ is a nowhere dense subset of $\mathbb{R}$. First, I asked, does every such $f$ have a continuous extension over the reals?

I soon realized that the answer is a blatant **no**. Take $\mathcal{N} = \{ \frac{1}{n} : n \in \mathbb{N_{\ge 1}} \}\cup \{0\}$ with $$f\left(\frac{1}{n}\right) = (-1)^n \\f(0)=0 $$

This function is discontinuous, so any extension of it will be discontinuous but, $f\restriction \mathcal{N}\setminus \{0\}\,$is continuous, and we can extend it continuously by adjoining the discrete points with line segments. Is it true that in order for $f$ to have a continuous extension over the reals it must **already** be continuous? Is there a characterization for when $f$ has a continuous extension?

Comment: @Thursday yeah whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the existence of continuous extension from a subset  $A\subset \mathbb R$, a necessary condition is for $f$ to be continuous on $A$. (Indeed, the restriction of any continuous function is continuous). When $A$ is closed, this is also sufficient: see [Tietze extension theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_extension_theorem). In general, it suffice to require uniform continuity on $A$: then the function extends continuously to $\overline{A}$, and the Tietze theorem applies.

(By the way, one could give a more direct/elementary proof of the special case of Tietze theorem for $\mathbb R$, taking advantage of the known structure of $\mathbb R\setminus A$.)

Comment: I forgot about Tietze, thanks.